# iOS screenshots for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I noticed a lot of apps (games) on the App Store have exactly the same screenshots for the iPhone and iPad, and I was curious what other developers do to achieve this. I assume that most developers would use their highest resolution device (i.e, iPhone 6 Plus) and then just resize/crop accordingly. However, there are some pitfalls with doing this, as UI elements can become distorted or cropped out if they are located near the edge of the screen. I suppose you could not render the UI elements when taking the screenshots, and then add them back in with Photoshop?

Comment: In xcode, you can just run an emulator of the device you want and take screenshots. No need to resize/crop. Just emulate the device you want and screenshot.

Comment: But each time you use a different device, you'll get a different screenshot.

Comment: To a certain extent, yes. If the tablet and phone are identically laid out, they will look very similar. Some apps will looks the same for tablet and phone.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer with my original post. I am talking specifically about games, where achieving identical images with different instances of the app running is very difficult, if not impossible (depending on the game).

Comment: Ah, it would probably be easy to just take a tablet screenshot and just crop off excess screen for the phone. I would almost need to see an example.